# EWS Python API issue: No Windows timezone name found for timezone "Asia/Kolkata"

Tags: python, python-3.x, exchangewebservices, pytz

I am using EWS API, from where i am booking an appointment. I am using Ubuntu.

When i am starting my application, i always get the error `No Windows timezone name found for timezone "Asia/Kolkata"`. i am using `python 3.6` for your information.

Things i did so far:

1. checked timezone of Ubuntu via timedatectl command which gives me
   timezone as Asia/Calcutta.
2. Updated all my libraries of pytz, tzlocal and exchangelib.

Comment: may be it is calcutta?

Comment: when the api is executed, it internally calls "tz = tzlocal.get_localzone()", where tzlocal is a package. It returns Asia/Kolkata, which exchangelib does not recognize.

Comment: exchange lib recognizes only calcutta. see it from here - https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/blob/master/exchangelib/winzone.py#L253

Comment: i created a PR for you - https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/pull/187.  could you please take latest from `exchangelib`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by Srinivas in https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/pull/187 and available in exchangelib v1.9.5.